# Use INDEX MATCH to find greater than/equal to value

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I've been searching online and in Excel Help but cannot find whether this is possible.

Given a list of numbers, values and a search term, I need to find the value whereby the value is greater than or equal to the search term.  See the example:

[image: Excel Index Match Example]

Excel returns *Red* but it should return *Orange* because 15 is greater than 10.
Other desired result examples would be:

- 5 = Red (or N/A)
- 25 = Yellow
- 63 = Violet
- 15434 = Violet (or N/A)

I realise that if I sort the list in descending order and use `-1` for the `MATCH` `[match_type]` argument, then it works okay, **but**, the list is over 1,000 rows and is far easier to read in ascending order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your desired results appear a little inconsistent. Why is the desired result for 15 Orange but that for 63 Indigo?

Are you in fact attempting to match based on whichever corresponding value is *absolutely* closest to the search value, whether below or above that value?

If so:

=INDEX(B4:B10,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ABS(A4:A10-B1)=MIN(INDEX(ABS(A4:A10-B1),,)),,),0))

though that still won't differentiate between e.g. Orange and Yellow for a search value of 25 (though I'm not sure how you are considering 25 "closer" to 30 than 20 in any case).

Regards

Comment: Ok. Then if you're happy with the N/As as you said for infra-Red and ultra-Violet(!):   =INDEX(B4:B10,MATCH(B1,A4:A10)+1)

Comment: Sorry that isn't working.  It's returning 10=Orange when 10 should be Red.

Comment: Apologies:  =INDEX(B4:B10,LOOKUP(10^10,MATCH(B1,A4:A10,{1,0})+{1,0}))

Answer (score 0):

Another method of doing this is to place the numbers and colours into a table, order numbers by highest to smallest and use the formula below:

```
=INDEX(B4:B10,MATCH(B1,A4:A10,-1))
```