# Excel - Finding nearest value in same list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of things along a road and am looking for a formula that can tell me where the nearest one is. Consider-

```
Road  Location (m)   Nearest
0001  0080           0230
0001  0230           0356
0001  0356           0400
0001  0400           0356
0002  0010           0034
0002  0034           0010
```

The 'Nearest' is what I am trying to achieve, i.e. for any given thing, what is the location value for the nearest thing, on the same road.

An index/match I found comes close, but doesn't have a condition that they're on the same road, and it doesn't exclude the current row.
([Use of INDEX MATCH to find absolute closest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770461/use-of-index-match-to-find-absolute-closest-value))

I am using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If A1:C1 are headers, then in C2:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MAX(IF(SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$100=A2,ABS($B$2:$B$100-B2)),2)=IF($A$2:$A$100=A2,ABS($B$2:$B$100-B2)),ROW($A$2:$A$100))))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

It will also error out with `#NUM` if a "road" only has one entry. In that case, wrap it in an `=IFERROR(...,"")`. Away from this, it should do exactly what you are looking for.

**EDIT**

to ignore doubles (so there will never be a 0), you can do it with `COUNTIFS` like this:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MAX(IF(SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$100=A2,ABS($B$2:$B$100-B2)),COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$100,A2,$B$2:$B$100,B2)+1)=IF($A$2:$A$100=A2,ABS($B$2:$B$100-B2)),ROW($A$2:$A$100))))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

So we simply change the `k` of `SMALL` from `2` to `COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$100,A2,$B$2:$B$100,B2)+1`.

If you still have any questions, just ask ;)

Comment: Thanks. I managed to come up with `=IF(A2=A1,IF(A2=A3,ABS(MIN(B3-B2,B2-B1)),ABS(B2-B1)),IF(A2=A3,ABS(B3-B2),))` however mine relies on the roadIDs being in order.

Comment: Although - is there a way to get it to ignore duplicates? I.e. if there are two things at the same location, it ignores the one at the same place, and returns the location to the nearest thing not at the same place? A nested IFNULL perhaps?

Comment: @PeterTomlinson added an edit to fully ignore doubles ;)