# Excel index match equal or greater than value error

Tags: excel, indexing, match, equals

hello first of all this is my code which returns the error

```
=INDEX(Steel_table!A3:A151,LOOKUP(10^10,MATCH(H7,Steel_table!C3:C151,{1,0})+{1,0}))
```

i have based this code from this thread:
[Use INDEX MATCH to find greater than/equal to value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757793/use-index-match-to-find-greater-than-equal-to-value)

This is the scenario
i have 2 sheets namely, stress analysis and steel table

the value that i would like to compare is located in the stress analysis sheet cell H7 and i would like to compare it to the steel table sheet from cell's values from C3 until C151.

please help me as it always returned an #N/A error

**Stress Analysis Sheet**

[image]

**Steel Table sheet**

[image]

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of **third argument** to MATCH functions must be considered depending on whether the lookup range is sorted or not.

The only time the range sort need not be taken into account is when using 0 - exact match. But exact match is not what you need since you are looking up calculated results against a table of prefixed values which won't likely be exactly matched...

So in order to use third argument of 1, the looking range should be sorted in ASCENDING order. In your case teh second value of the lookup range is larger than your lookup value, and so is the first, so Excel shortcuts to N/A, assuming that no smaller value will be found further down.

The reverse logic is true for using -1.

You can simply use the difference of the lookup values and the range to obtain the smallest one. So we use the MIN function. But you only want positive differences , so you'll need to transform all negative numbers into a ridiculously large number(such as 10^10), so that they are not used as potential minimum values:

`INDEX(Steel_table!$A$3:$A$151, MATCH(MIN(IF(Steel_table!C3:C151-H7>=0, Steel_table!C3:C151-H7, 10^10)), Steel_table!C3:C151-H7,0))`

Comment: still does not work sir , i have uploaded the trial file here hope you can give me some comment to help me fix the error. thanks
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByBx0gzVtGKJY1FiaXVKVldUb3c

Comment: It works. Two things, 1) My mistake - you MUST enter the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter ( I sometimes forget to tell people that with array formula solutions) 2) Please make sure that the worksheet name as seen in the tab is exactly the same as the one in the formula reference. `Steel_table` needs to be the same in the formula reference as it is in the worksheet tab. It works - I have tested on your workbook after doing these things, and I get L4 x 3.5 x 1/4

Comment: hello MacroMarc, thank you i already made it work using your formula, 

sorry for being ignorant but my mistake is that i always cancel the prompt to where to get the values from, that's why it always return an error.

Thanks again. problem solved

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the smallest value in Steel_table!C3:C151) that is equal or greater then the value in cel H7:

```
=MIN(IF((Steel_table!C3:C151)>=H7,(Steel_table!C3:C151)))
```

It is an array formula, so confirm with [Control-Shift-Enter]. The output will be 1451.61. It will return 0 when there is no equal or greater value.

Comment: still does not work sir , i have uploaded the trial file here hope you can give me some comment to help me fix the error. thanks
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByBx0gzVtGKJY1FiaXVKVldUb3c

Comment: OK. I think i understand what you want know. See my updated answer

Comment: @Maurice France: If this is still not working, please inform me what is not working and what is the value you expect of the formula.

Comment: hello Marco Vos, thank you for your input
sorry for being ignorant but my mistake is that i always cancel the prompt to where to get the values from, that's why it always return an error.

Thanks again. problem solved

Comment: @Maurice France: Just out of curiousity: what was the outputvalue of the formula you were looking for, in your examplesheet?

Comment: L4 x 3.5 x 1/4 sir marco vos