# Getting the next higher value with VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
        A          B                 C                 D
1         0     Product 1          7.500           Product 4
2     1.000     Product 2
3     5.000     Product 3
4    10.000     Product 4
5
```

In **Cell C1** I type a random number (in this case 7.500). Now I want that in **Cell D1** the corresponding Product is shown to the value in **Cell C1**. Since 7.500 does not exist in **Column A** the next **higher** value should be used. In this case 10.000 which belongs to Product 4.

I tried to go with the following formula in **Cell D2** but instead of getting Product 4 I get #NV as a result.

```
=INDEX(A1:B4;MATCH(C1;A1:A4;-1);2)
```

The only solution I found so far was changing the values in **Column A** from *ascending* to *descending*. However, I would prefer to have a solution which does not require a change of the order in the list.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue without changing the order in the list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757793/use-index-match-to-find-greater-than-equal-to-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unsorted data you can use below formula::

```
=INDEX(B1:B4,MATCH(SMALL($A$1:$A$4,COUNTIF($A$1:$A$4,"<"&C1)+1),A1:A4,0))
```

See image for reference

[image]