# Index match find closest value with multiple search criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to find a closest absolute value with index match. I looked at several other posts like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757793/use-index-match-to-find-greater-than-equal-to-value) but what i am trying to do is a bit different as i want to add multiple search criterias.

As you can see [image: screen shot],  I am trying to get the absolute closest time for a specific person.

I am using the formula  =index(C2:C21,match(F4,B2:B21,-1),match(E4,A2:A21,0)) and  I had to copy column B in column C to make my 1st match work. The result is shown in G4. Unfortunately I am struggling to get the correct result.

Effectively I would like use the formula that was posted in the previous post (see link at the top)  =INDEX(E2:E21,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ABS(D1:D21-I4)=MIN(INDEX(ABS(D2:D21-I4),,)),,),0)) 
with with a search criteria (the name of the person).

Any help would be much appreciated

Thank you

Thanks @avram 
I still end up with some cases where the formula does not work. See below. in G6 and G7 i should get 10:25. (You can ignore column A)
[image: screen shot 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula in G4,

```
=index(C$2:C$21, match(min(index(abs(index(C$2:C$21+(B$2:B$21<>E4)*1E+99, , )-F4), , )), if(B$2:B$21=E4, abs(C$2:C$21-F4), 1E+99), 0))
```

This will work in either [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets) as a standard (non-array/non-CSE) formula or [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) as an array (CSE) formula.

[image]

If anyone else wants to tackle this problem with a more elegant formula, you can copy the sample data from this publicly shared google-sheet.

[Index match find closest value with multiple search criteria](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aM8CZ5KZ0FoVuKmzFHFfHQIEUbi4iPkZh-yNIUn3zrE/edit?usp=sharing)

Perhaps this may exempt a fourth person from retyping the same tired data that the op delivered in image(s).

Comment: That works perfectly fine, thank you very much. If you have 2 mins to spare i would also be grateful if you could explain a bit the formula (especially the 1E+99).

Answer (score 1):

A very simple approach using a "helper" column with data like:

[image]

We want the closest absolute match for larry to 10:15 AM.  We enter *larry* in **E1** and *10:15 AM* in **F1**

Then in **D2** we enter:

```
=IF(A2=$E$1,ABS(B2-$F$1),"")
```

and copy downward. *(this is the absolute difference for larry)*  Finally in **E2**:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MIN(D:D),D:D,0))
```

[image]

With bigger tables having more columns, it is very easy to add additional criteria if needed.

Comment: @AvramPenner  Thanks.................I am hoping someone posts a solution without the need for a helper column.

Comment: I'll keep thinking on it.

Comment: I think I cracked it. Added a new answer, lmk your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses `Array Formulas` which must be entered using `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.  It's kind of complicated, so I'll do my best to explain and will revise if necessary.  Here's a screenshot:[image: Screenshot]

Here is the formula in its raw form; names are entered in column A, Times in Column B.
`=INDEX(B1:B7,MATCH(MIN(IF(A1:A7=D2,ABS(E2-B1:B7),"")),IF(A1:A7=D2,ABS(E2-B1:B7),"")))`

As you might suspect, it uses `INDEX/MATCH` to get the job done, but the key is using an `IF` statement to generate both the search criteria and the array that the `MATCH` function searches within.  Let's break it down.

*Sec 1, Match Search Array*
`IF(A1:A7=D2,ABS(E2-B1:B7),"")`
This creates the Search array for the match function. If the name in `D2` (our criteria) is equal to the name in the search array, it return the absolute value of the difference between the criteria time and the time in the array we're searching. Otherwise it returns a blank value. Do not use 0 for this as it will skew the match result.

*Sec 2, Match Search Criteria*
`MIN(IF(A1:A7=D2,ABS(E2-B1:B7),""))`
This tells us the smallest value in the above array.  We use this value as the search criteria in the MATCH function.

*Sec 3, putting 1 & 2 Together*
`MATCH(MIN(IF(A1:A7=D2,ABS(E2-B1:B7),"")),IF(A1:A7=D2,ABS(E2-B1:B7),""))` This searches for the smallest abs difference defined in Section 2 *within* the array created in Section 1 and returns the row number.

*Sec 4, Indexing the times*
`=INDEX(B1:B7,MATCH(MIN(IF(A1:A7=D2,ABS(E2-B1:B7),"")),IF(A1:A7=D2,ABS(E2-B1:B7),"")))`
This returns the time value from column B in whatever row is identified by the Match function above.

Hopefully this all makes sense.  Remember to enter it as an array formula.

Comment: This is essentially the same as the other answer but nests the "helper column" within the array formula.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. I still end up with cases where it does not work and i am struggling to understand why. I am still new to stackoverflow and i am not sure how to post screenshot in the comments. so i have edited my first question. @AvramPenner

Comment: Yes i am. does it change somehting ?

Comment: Yes. Sheets treats array formulas differently than excel. I'll take a peak there when I can.