# Updating a cell value based on three conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

We have 1000's of records in different excel sheets and we have to compile it into one based on unique_id. One of the tasks is to update a column "Desc" based on unique_id and value range from other two columns.

[image]

As pointed out in the image - col D "Desc" has to be updated by values from col "K". But while doing so - ***col b & c "From, To"*** values should be within the range of ***col i & j "From, to"***.

These are the conditions to update the "Desc" column.

1) ID should be same

2) ***Col b "From"*** should be nearest greater than ***Col i "From"***

3) ***Col c "To"*** should be nearest greater or less than ***Col j "To"***

4) Conditions 2 and 3 is to retrieve values within the range. Not sure if this condition works

I've treid with the formula mentioned in [Use INDEX MATCH to find greater than/equal to value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757793/use-index-match-to-find-greater-than-equal-to-value). But i don't know how to make it work for my conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following array formula (entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) maybe:

```
=INDEX(K:K,SUM(($H:$H=A2)*($I:$I<=B2)*($J:$J>=C2)*ROW($J:$J)))
```

[image]

`MATCH` mostly works for single column/row matches, and for multiple columns, you would have to merge ID, From and To, except that because of the ranges, concatenation makes this method more complex. If the retrieved value was a number, then `SUMIFS` would have been an easier method, but the value is a text, so it cannot be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved our problem. One question. Is it possible to give a condition like "nearest greater/lesser value" instead of "greater than/less than" ?

Comment: @joseph_k Sure, you can use `>` and `<` instead of `>=` and `<=`

Comment: @joseph_k or did you mean nearest, regardless of whether it's greater or less than?